# d3 points over openlayers map

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, openlayers

I am trying to plot points in a openlayers map from a geoJson file with d3 but nothing appears on the screen. I was able to plot points in a random place that moved around when I scrolled the map but I need the points to be fixed on it's latlng. This is my code so far, I am using rlayers lib from react.

````
import geojson from './teste2.json'
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import { Point } from "ol/geom";
import "ol/ol.css";
import { RMap, ROSM, RLayerVector, RFeature, ROverlay, RStyle } from "rlayers";


export const MainPage = () => {

    const mapRef = useRef();
    const containerRef = useRef();
    const width = 600
    const height = 600

    useEffect(() => {
        const container = containerRef.current;

        if (container) {
            const svg = d3
                .select(container)
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            const projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize(
                [width, height],
                geojson
            );

            const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

            const feature = svg
                .selectAll("path")
                .data(geojson.features)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .style("fill", "red");

            const mapContainer = mapRef.current;
            const updateOverlay = () => {
                const topLeft = projection([mapContainer.left, mapContainer.top]);

                svg
                    .attr("width", 800)
                    .attr("height", 1000)
                    .style("left", `${topLeft[0]}px`)
                    .style("top", `${topLeft[1]}px`);

                feature.attr(
                    "transform",
                    `translate(${-topLeft[0]},${-topLeft[1]})`
                );
            };

            updateOverlay();

            mapContainer.addEventListener("click", updateOverlay);
            mapContainer.addEventListener("moveend", updateOverlay);
            mapContainer.addEventListener("zoomend", updateOverlay);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <RMap
            ref={mapRef}
            height="600px"
            width="600px"
            className="example-map"
            initial={{
                center: fromLonLat([-57.75,
                -31]), zoom: 5
            }}
        >
            <ROSM />
            <RLayerVector zIndex={10}>

                <RFeature
                    geometry={new Point(fromLonLat([2.364, 48.82]))}
                    onClick={(e) =>
                        e.map.getView().fit(e.target.getGeometry().getExtent(), {
                            duration: 250,
                            maxZoom: 15,
                        })
                    }
                >
                    <ROverlay>
                        <div ref={containerRef} />
                    </ROverlay>
                </RFeature>
            </RLayerVector>
            <RLayerVector>
                <RFeature>

                </RFeature>
            </RLayerVector>
        </RMap >
    )
}
```
````

Comment: Have you tried this approach?  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/d3.html

Comment: I have but I will try it again

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Javascript `d3PointLayer` class that you can use for this purpose. The implementation is in [this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/53f040a8e992d4fe) and here it is in action:

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="module">
  import {Runtime, Inspector} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/runtime@5/dist/runtime.js";
  import define from "https://api.observablehq.com/d/53f040a8e992d4fe.js?v=3";
  new Runtime().module(define, name => {
    if (name === "map") return new Inspector(document.querySelector("#map"));
  });
</script>
```

Depending on your setup, the class might or might not work without modification. If you're using Node, as in [this OpenLayers example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/d3.html), you'd probably import names directly from their module, rather than refer to full name spaces. Thus, where I've written

```
class d3PointLayer extends ol.layer.Layer {
  ...
}
```

You'd want

```
import Layer from 'ol/layer.js';

// and then
class d3PointLayer extends Layer {
  ...
}
```